# How do you create a javascript module that outputs some logic

Tags: javascript, module

I've just started learning how to work with Javascript in a modular way, and so far have been moving functions into their own modules to avoid repeating myself.

There are some cases where I have a piece of logic that isn't a function but I'd like to move into a module of some sort.

I'm having to repeat this code a few times in different areas on my app:

```
  var variable_one = 1;
  var variable_two = 2;
  var variable_three = 3;
  var variable_four = 4;

  if (true) { 
    variable_one = 10;
  }
```

Would I create a function that returns this code? If so how do I handle the multiple lines. I imagine this is beginner stuff.

In short how can I output these 7 lines in 10 different areas in my .js file by repeating one function or similar.

**Improving on the question**

Is there a better way to write these functions to avoid the repeating of the initial variables and random function, whilst keeping the variables and random function within the function.

```
function function_one() {

      var variable_one = 1;
      var variable_two = 2;
      var variable_three = 3;
      var variable_four = 4;

      randomfunction();

      if (true) { 
        variable_one = 1;
      }

}

function function_two() {

      var variable_one = 1;
      var variable_two = 2;
      var variable_three = 3;
      var variable_four = 4;

      randomfunction();

      if (true) { 
        variable_one = 8;
      }

}

function function_three() {

      var variable_one = 1;
      var variable_two = 2;
      var variable_three = 3;
      var variable_four = 4;

      randomfunction();

      if (true) { 
        variable_one = 2;
      }

}

function function_four() {

      var variable_one = 1;
      var variable_two = 2;
      var variable_three = 3;
      var variable_four = 4;

      randomfunction();

      if (true) { 
        variable_one = 5;
      }

}
```

Comment: To help you, please tell (and maybe link) us about which tutorials you have already read about this question. We then can fill the missing parts.

Comment: I should have probably left out most of the logic, it's pointless to the question. Editing.

Comment: Ok that seems shorter now, but please be so kind and answer my previous question, so we can help you more precise.

Comment: "how do I handle the multiple lines" — This gives the impression that you seem to think a function can only hold one statement. I've no idea what gave you that idea.

Comment: I'm not under that impression, but I'm wondering if the approach would be to use return and then list out the code line by line?

Comment: Does this help @spyro "In short how can I output these 7 lines in 10 different areas in my .js file by repeating one function or similar." I'm not looking at any tutorial in particular I just want to reduce repeating long lines of similar code in my .js file.

Comment: @jermainecraig please tell us, wherre you got those information and what tutorials you have read/watched about this topic. Stackoverflow is no place for getting broad tutorials. That's why i am asking politely, no offense.

Comment: No offence taken. I've been exposed to creating modules in node, and it's made me think there's a better way to repeatedly output the same 7 lines of code. I'm asking if that's is in fact correct. @spyro

Comment: @jermainecraig The question u are asking (as i now think i fully understand it) is  basic and beginner stuff of every proramming language. Doing, waht you are asking, is the stuff that should be learned not by asking a specific use-case on stackoverflow, but by reading more into how JS and `exports`, `objects` and `functions` work. You can read it here (https://www.kaplankomputing.com/blog/tutorials/javascript/understanding-imports-exports-es6/) but also everywhere on the internet. The reason, why i deny to give a specific answer is, that after that, you will have a followup-question.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I've improved the question to hopefully make it clearer. I think it's not a yes or no answer, and so I won't have a follow up. Is there a better way to write that code removing the repetitions? If not, ok. If yes, what is the way?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are actually trying to achieve with those functions. What are the variables for for example? Why are you using those `if` statements that will always evaluate to true? My concern at the moment is that you lack an understanding of the basics and are jumping ahead to an advanced feature that will just lead to confusion and bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want to do as I'm not sure how these variables are used but generally this is how you make variables in a module available to be imported:

Create a `variables.js` file:

```
export var variable_one = 10;
export var variable_two = 2;
export var variable_three = 3;
export var variable_four = 4;
```

In your other files:

```
import { variable_one, variable_two, variable_three, variable_four } from './variables.js'
```

You could also package these all into a single object and export that.

Comment: I most highly recommend to not just blindly follow this answer. Please learn more about structuring in JS, objects and import/exporting things. Otherwise you are learning in the wrong order and you will stay to wrong patterns and ways of doing those things.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your updated question:

Yes, there is a better way:

Put the 4 variables into another JS-file.

Then, from within this new js-file, you export them and on the other-code you import them.

There are many mistakes you can do if you are not familiar with how to import/export, so if you havent already: Learn about this.

I you need help on how to search for these basic tutorials, please tell us.